# Retrieving class variables through usage of `.class`

Tags: java

Is it possible to access a public variable in a class while if the only available access to that class is its `.class`.

As an example if I have `A_VARIABLE` in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`, if I put the *reference* to each class `Object` into an HashSet, am I able to retrieve the `A_VARIABLE` for each item in the HashSet.

```
public class ClassA{
    public static final String A_VARIABLE = "ABC";
}

public class ClassB{
    public static final String A_VARIABLE = "123";
}


public class ClassC{
    private void someMethod(){
        HashSet<Class> someClassHashSet = new HashSet<>();
        someClassHashSet.add(ClassA.class);
        someClassHashSet.add(ClassB.class);

        for (Class someClass : someClassHashSet){
            System.out.println("The value is: " + /*someClass.A_VARIABLE*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Which I would like to print:

```
The Value is: ABC
The Value is: 123
```

Comment: `ClassA.A_VARIABLE` (it's a constant field) and an `equals` on the class should do the trick

Comment: @RC wouldn't this mean that he needs to cast his Class objects...?

Comment: @schneida nope, see Rahul answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you'll need reflection which is slower than direct access but still used widely:

```
for (Class someClass : someClassHashSet){
        Object value = null;
        try {
            value = someClass.getField("A_VARIABLE").get(null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("The value is: " + value);
}
```

You see that this code gets the value of a field, that you only reference by a string. The `null` in `.get(null)` is because your fields are static. If they were not, you would have to provide an instance of which you'd like to get the value.

Note: Your someMethod() is missing a return value, eg void.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it following way

```
 for (Class someClass : someClassHashSet){
         if (ClassA.class.equals(someClass)) {
            System.out.println("The value is: " + ClassA.A_VARIABLE );  
          } else if (ClassB.class.equals(someClass)) {
            System.out.println("The value is: " + ClassB.A_VARIABLE );
          }
 }
```